# Ruby string repetition without integer

Tags: ruby, string, repeat

I just found a `CodeGolf` answer here http://repl.it/2Om/6:

```
puts"The eight#{e="een-hundreds were a time for "}rum.
The ninet#{e}fun.
The two-thousands are a time to run
a civilized classroom.
"*(?X-??)
```

Original post: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40250

I am curious, how does it work? I have never seen `(?X-??)` before. What's happening here?

Comment: Warning: Code golf is interesting/a curiosity, however NEVER use it in production code. Only as a an example of "huh, look at that". Ruby tries to make it more difficult to write code that is indistinguishable from line-noise, unlike Perl and C/C++ however it's possible to do so by trying hard. Inflicting that on someone else is a way to be chastised in a code-review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

?Char gives the ASCII code of Char.

```
?X = "X".ord = 88
?? = "?".ord = 63
?X - ?? = 88-63 = 25
There is your integer: 25
Then "a"*25 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Comment: In recent Ruby versions `?X` returns `"X"`, not 88.

Comment: Probably not on ruby 1.8, which is the version on which he was running the code.

Comment: I have been wasting time on this. I tried running `?X`, `??` & `?X - ??` in `irb` but it kept throwing an error. I checked the repl link again and this code works for `Ruby 1.8`. Thanks for the explanation. I can sleep now.

Comment: Yeah it seems they did some pretty nice changes. Similarly `"blabla"[0]` now returns `"b"`, not `98`.